# Fast way to manually mod a number

Tags: c#, algorithm, modulo

I need to be able to calculate (a^b) % c for very large values of a and b (which individually are pushing limit and which cause overflow errors when you try to calculate a^b). For small enough numbers, using the identity (a^b)%c = (a%c)^b%c works, but if c is too large this doesn't really help. I wrote a loop to do the mod operation manually, one a at a time:

```
private static long no_Overflow_Mod(ulong num_base, ulong num_exponent, ulong mod) 
    {
        long answer = 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < num_exponent; x++)
        {
            answer = (answer * num_base) % mod;
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

but this takes a very long time. Is there any simple and fast way to do this operation without actually having to take a to the power of b AND without using time-consuming loops? If all else fails, I can make a bool array to represent a huge data type and figure out how to do this with bitwise operators, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Sounds like an Euler problem... If it is, you should clearly state that in the question instead of trying to cheat...

Comment: Knowing the range of a, b, and c might help us.

Comment: This bool array idea is not going to work.  Bool arrays are not bitvectors, and they are not stored packed.  Plus, then you're not relying on direct hardware math.

Comment: I don't know if it's really cheating. Reading about that problem it looks like he knows the answer he just wants to know how to do it within reasonable time constraints in c#.

Comment: I actually wasn't trying to solve that problem at all, I need this algorithm for an encryption program I'm writing.

Comment: Is this for your own edification, or are you planning on actually relying upon your algorithm to protect your customers from evildoers?  If the former, you go. If the latter, I strongly urge you to reconsider.

Answer (score 9):

I guess you are looking for : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_reduction
or the simpler way based on Modular Exponentiation (from wikipedia)

```
Bignum modpow(Bignum base, Bignum exponent, Bignum modulus) {

    Bignum result = 1;

    while (exponent > 0) {
        if ((exponent & 1) == 1) {
            // multiply in this bit's contribution while using modulus to keep result small
            result = (result * base) % modulus;
        }
        // move to the next bit of the exponent, square (and mod) the base accordingly
        exponent >>= 1;
        base = (base * base) % modulus;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If the modulus is smaller than the exponent, I think you could improve this algorithm by taking the modulus of the count of 1 bits of the exponents and only do that many loop iterations.  One could actually do even better than that in some cases.  See Kai's answer.

Comment: i think you can break out whenever result = 0

          result = (result * base) % modulus;
          if (result == 0) break;

Comment: The formatting screwed up my comment.  Add "if (result == 0) break;" after the calculation of result.

Comment: Actually before you mutliply result*base, check base==0 and break then.

Comment: You can break out at the bottom after "exponent >>= 1;" if exponent == 0 and avoid having to do the last mulitply and mod.

Comment: adding the `if (exponent == 0) break;` actually slows it down slightly in a ulong implementation - running a long prime test takes 32.798 without it and 32.733 with it after on second run; testing base is slightly slower and testing result is quite a bit slower (about 33 seconds). Sometimes shortcuts aren't optimizations.

Answer (score 6):

Fast Modular Exponentiation (I think that's what it's called) might work.

```
Given a, b, c and a^b (mod c):

1. Write b as a sum of powers of 2. (If b=72, this is 2^6 + 2^3 )
2. Do:
    (1) a^2 (mod c) = a*
    (2) (a*)^2 (mod c) = a*
    (3) (a*)^2 (mod c) = a*
    ...
    (n) (a*)^2 (mod c) = a*

3. Using the a* from above, multiply the a* for the powers of 2 you identified. For example:
    b = 72, use a* at 3 and a* at 6.
    a*(3) x a*(6) (mod c)

4. Do the previous step one multiplication at a time and at the end, you'll have a^b % c.
```

Now, how you're going to do that with data types, I don't know. As long as your datatype can support c^2, i think you'll be fine.

If using strings, just create string versions of add, subtract, and multiply (not too hard). This method should be quick enough doing that. (and you can start step 1 by a mod c so that a is never greater than c).

EDIT: Oh look, a wiki page on [Modular Exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of Fast Modular Exponentiation (suggested in one of the earlier answers) in java.  Shouldn't be too hard to convert that to C#

http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/crypto/a01/FastPow.html

and the source...

http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/crypto/a01/FastPow.java

Answer (score 2):

Python has pow(a,b,c) which returns (a**b)%c (only faster), so there must be some clever way to do this. Maybe they just do the identity you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Short of writing your own [fast modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), the simplest idea I can come up with, is to use the F# BigInt type: `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Types.BigInt` which supports operations with arbitrarily large scale - including exponentiation and modular arithmetic.

It's a built-in type that will be part of the full .NET framework with the next release. You don't need to use F# to use BitInt - you can make use of it directly in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking over the Decimal documentation and seeing if it meets your requirements since it is a built in type and can use the mod operator. If not then you're going to need an arbitrary precision library like java's Bignum.

Comment: no shit, i was saying like, as in he would need to find an equivalent. way to not read.

Comment: He said *like* Java's Bignum.  Not *use" Java's Bignum.  

Given that he knows about C#'s decimal type, it's probably a good bet that he knows the question is about C#.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

C#: Doing a modulus (mod) operation on a very large number (> Int64.MaxValue)
http://www.del337ed.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/04/c-doing-a-modulus-mod-operation-on-a-very-large-number-int64maxvalue/

Answer (score 1):

You can try **factoring** 'a' into sufficiently small numbers.

If the factors of 'a' are 'x', 'y', and 'z', then

a^b = (x^b)(y^b)(z^b).

Then you can use your identity:  (a^b)%c = (a%c)^b%c

Comment: Except that factoring is a much more difficult problem than modulus

Comment: I would just start out dividing a/2 in a loop until it didn't divide evenly.... Then a/3, etc with prime numbers until 'a' was "sufficiently small" for a^b not to overflow. Then complete the operation as outlined by the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like there's some kind of relation between power and mod. Power is just repeated multiplication and mod is related to division. We know that multiplication and division are inverses, so through that connection I would assume there's a correlation between power and mod.

For example, take powers of 5:

```
5 % 4 = 1
25 % 4 = 1
125 % 4 = 1
625 % 4 = 1
...
```

The pattern is clear that 5 ^ b % 4 = 1 for all values of b.

It's less clear in this situation:

```
5 % 3 = 2
25 % 3 = 1
125 % 3 = 2
625 % 3 = 1
3125 % 3 = 2
15625 % 3 = 1
78125 % 3 = 2
...
```

But there's still a pattern.

If you could work out the math behind the patterns, I wouldn't be surprised if you could figure out the value of the mod without doing the actual power.

Comment: The pattern is obvious and well-known.  It's Fermat's Little Theorem (and the identity is used in the OP).

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, thanks for pointing me to it. It's only obvious if you've considered this kind of problem before and I'm grateful to have derived the idea myself :)

Comment: Where is Fermat's little theorem used in the OP?

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too quick.  This isn't Fermat.  Both Kai's post and the OP are basic modular multiplicatioon.

Answer (score 0):

Can you factor a, b, or c?  Does C have a known range?

These are 32 bit integers!  Go check this [site](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ModulusDivisionEasy)

For instance, here is how you get the mod of n%d where d 1>>s (1,2,4,8,...)

```
  int n = 137;     // numerator
  int d = 32;      // denom d will be one of: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...
  int m;           // m will be n % d
  m = n & (d - 1);
```

There is code for n%d where d is 1>>s - 1 (1, 3, 7, 15, 31, ...)

This is only going to really help if c is small though, like you said.

Comment: do you mean, "where d is 1 << (s-1)"?

Comment: yeah.  I can't even copy from another website without making a mistake!

Answer (score -2):

Looks like homework in cryptography.

Hint: check out [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem).